# Getting slider-arrows to "glow" when hovered over

Tags: html, css, slider

So, I'm trying to get my nav-arrows to "lighten" up as they are hovered over. The images themselves have 2 "states", one being lit up and one being not. The current one's that are always active are the non-lit up, and I saw somewhere something about altering the position of the image (the glowing ones are further down in the `.png`) when they're hovered over. What would this look like (when noting that i have .hero-carousel-nav and all of that)?

Implenting something kind-of like this? This would move the `.png` when hovered over, making it show the "glowing" arrow instead? If so, what should I put instead of "something.here" below?

`.something.here-arrow-right:hover {
    background-position: 0 -40px;
}`

Here's an example of my arrow to the right.

**CSS**

```
.hero-carousel-nav li.next a { 
background: url('../images/deadmau5/large-arrow-right.png') -5px -7px no-repeat;
display: inline-block;
width: 105px;        /*width of your img*/
height: 105px;      /*height of your img*/
font-size: 0px; 
right: -15px;  /*this is better than 1px*/
bottom: 100px;
overflow:hidden;
outline:none;
z-index: 3;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
.hero-carousel-nav li.next a:hover{
    background-position: 0 -40px;
}
```

Comment: I did exactly that put forgot the `a` after `next`! Thank you!